# Java Calendar Strange behaviour

Tags: java, calendar

I am using calendar object in java to convert an input date(year/month/date etc are getting from network ) to epoch time. I am reusing same calendar object . Sometimes the year i am getting from
network is 0 and there was no validation for this once. Once this happens the whenever i convert the date to epoch, the epoch time im getting is always negative. Is this a valid behaviour

Please find sample code and result   I got while doing a unit test for this issue.

```
    Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();        
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0); 
    System.out.println("time 1 : "+cal.getTimeInMillis());  
    System.out.println("Date 1 : "+new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));  

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020); 
    System.out.println("time 2 : "+cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("Date 2 : "+new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));  

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    System.out.println("time 3 : "+cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("Date 3 : "+new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Output for this code is
Time 1 : -62151385126938
Date 1 : Sun Jul 04 11:51:13 IST 1

Time 2 : -125866201126938
Date 2 : Wed Jul 04 11:51:13 IST 2020

Time 3 : -125540041126938
Date 3 : Fri Nov 04 11:51:13 IST 2010

Is this an expected behaviour for java Calendar?

My JDK version is
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.252.09.1 (build 1.8.0_252-b09)

Edit:
There are other option/class to fix this issue, But my purpose is to find the root cause of this behaviour

Comment: Why are you using Calendar and not `java.time`?

Comment: Can you provide a full example of a datetime `String` to be parsed?

Comment: I certainly do not expect the times to be negative. I'm inclined to say this is one of the many bugs of `Calendar`. Setting year to 0 somehow messes it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an expected behaviour for java Calendar?

My perhaps polemic answer is that `Calendar` pretty often behaves contrary to expectations. It has been designed and documented to do so. I understand your confusion.

There is no year 0. So a first expectation might have been that `Calendar` should throw an exception when you try to set the year of era to 0. With standard settings it doesn’t. Instead it extrapolates: year 0 is taken to mean the year before year 1 , so that is year 1 BC. In your output you can see that the year is 1 (not 0); but what you cannot see is the era, it’s BC, not AD (CE). So let’s add a couple of lines that print the era to your code:

```
    Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.format("Initial:   Era %s year %d%n",
            cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.ERA, Calendar.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH),
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
    System.out.format("Year 0:    Era %s year %d%n",
            cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.ERA, Calendar.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH),
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("time 1 :   "+cal.getTimeInMillis());  
    System.out.println("Date 1 :   "+new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

When I ran the code just now, the output was:

> ```
> Initial:   Era AD year 2020
> Year 0:    Era BC year 1
> time 1 :   -62151371618330
> Date 1 :   Sun Jul 04 11:06:21 CET 1
> ```

Next, `Calendar.YEAR` means year of era, at least to a `GregorianCalendar` (which is the concrete subclass of `Calendar` of which you got an instance from `Calendar.getInstance()`). So when next you set `YEAR`, that is, year of era, to 2020, the `Calendar` stays before Christ (before the common era), so you get 2020 BC, more than 4000 years ago. And your milliseconds “grow” to approximately double magnitude of the already negative value.

```
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020); 
    System.out.format("Year 2020: Era %s year %d%n",
            cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.ERA, Calendar.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH),
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("time 2 :   "+cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("Date 2 :   "+new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

> ```
> Year 2020: Era BC year 2020
> time 2 :   -125866187618330
> Date 2 :   Wed Jul 04 11:06:21 CET 2020
> ```

IMHO it’s a fine case for avoiding the `Calendar` class.

### java.time

And yes, if only for other readers, there are alternatives.

First, you should not try to handle a meaningless year. I don’t know your situation and requirements, so cannot tell you what to do when you get a year that is 0 or negative, but you need to decide, and you need to check and act appropriately. What you have been doing until now is wrong, as you are aware.

Second, very obviously you should use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    zdt = zdt.withYear(0);
    System.out.println(zdt);
    System.out.println(zdt.toEpochSecond());

    zdt = zdt.withYear(2020);
    System.out.println(zdt);
    System.out.println(zdt.toEpochSecond());

    zdt = zdt.withYear(2010);
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

> ```
> 0000-07-04T11:23:08.573357+00:50:20[Europe/Copenhagen]
> -62151197232
> 2020-07-04T11:23:08.573357+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> 1593854588
> 2010-07-04T11:23:08.573357+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> ```

You notice in this output that the seconds since the epoch turn positive again after they have been negative. In java.time a year means the *proleptic year*, that is, a signed year. Proleptic year 0 is 1 BC, -1 means 2 BC, etc. So year 0 is just any other year and doesn’t incur any weird behaviour.

Also java.time *does* object to setting year of era to 0, which might have helped you discover earlier that you had an issue:

```
    zdt = zdt.with(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 0);
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for YearOfEra (valid values 1 - 999999999/1000000000): 0
>   at java.base/java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidValue(ValueRange.java:311)
>   at java.base/java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:717)
>   at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.with(LocalDate.java:1048)
>   at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.with(LocalDateTime.java:970)
>   at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.with(ZonedDateTime.java:1312)
>   at ovv.so.date.special.SetCalendarYear0.main(SetCalendarYear0.java:25)
> ```

Comment: *There is no year 0.* - [Absolutely correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero). Also, a great answer!

Comment: Great answer , Thanks for reply

Answer (score 5):

> I am using calendar object

Stop doing that. Never use the terrible `Calendar` and `Date` classes. Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> Sometimes the year i am getting from network is 0 and there was no validation for this once. Once this happens the whenever i convert the date to epoch, the epoch time im getting is always negative. Is this a valid behaviour

Yes, a negative count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC would be correct for a date with year zero. Year 0000 occurred over two thousands years ago, so that would be a very large number of milliseconds counting backwards from 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

I understand that you see `Calendar` returning bizarre negative numbers after resetting for contemporary years. If you want more info, see excellent [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727393/642706) In my opinion: there is no purpose to investigating `Calendar` now that we have *java.time*. Let’s bury the dead, and move on.

If you must inter-operate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert back and forth between the legacy classes and the modern. Look to new methods added to the old classes. Minimize your use of the old legacy classes.

```
if( myCalendar instanceof GregorianCalendar ) 
{
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalendar ).toZonedDateTime() ;
}
```

…and…

```
Calendar myCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

You said:

> I am reusing same calendar object .

Stop doing that. Reusing objects of that class leads to various problems.

One of the important design considerations in *java.time* is the use of only immutable objects, to avoid these reuse problems.

> am using calendar object in java to convert an input date(year/month/date

You do not show us this code, so I cannot help you any further.

Search Stack Overflow before posting. All this has been covered many times already.

Comment: Yes, it can be negative f, but my doubt is , setting  year to  0 once mes-sup the behaviour of calendar object.   In this a bug or expected behaviour

Comment: @Dijesh Yes that class is easily screwed up. Yes that class has many flaws. Stop using it. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community unanimously gave up on that class years ago. So should you.

Comment: Now im  not using this code, i updated with java.time and i have fixed the issue.  I am trying to understand why this error happened in first place

Comment: @Dijesh There is really no benefit to trying to figure out the bizarre mess that is the `Calendar` class,  now that we have its successor in *java,time*. Stick with *java.time*, and move on to more important matters.

Comment: @Dijesh OpenJDK is _open_, you can go check out its source code and trace what exactly happens when you set year to 0. But as Basil Bourque said, I don't see why doing this would be beneficial at all.

Comment: @Sweeper   : Thanks for the reply, you are right .i think we are wasting time on this topic